# Installing Glog linking error

Tags: c++

I am new to programming. I want to install Glog on my Windows 10 system. I have followed the instructions found in a Stack Overflow thread with the same name.

I used cmake and Visual Studio 2015 to build the project.
First anomaly of the built file: I noticed that in the glog directory the header file "log_severity.h" was missing. To alleviate this problem, I copied the "log_severity.h" from the GitHub repository and pasted it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOxhn.jpg

I then created a sample program that just initializes the logger by only using

> google::InitGoogleLogging(argv[0]);
>   in the main.

Before compiling I direct the linker to include an additional include directory. This include directory is the one with the header files as in the second image (with the log_severity.h etc.):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yIzy.jpg

Yet I still receive a linking error when compiling the code:

> 1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl google::InitGoogleLogging(char const *)" (__imp_?InitGoogleLogging@google@@YAXPEBD@Z) referenced in function main
>   1>D:\Documents\Programming\C++\Programme\GLogTest\GlogTest\x64\Debug\GlogTest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot of any answers.

Comment: "found in a stackoverflow thread with the same name." A link would be better.

Comment: I cant post more than two links, I can add it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41766969/installing-glog-on-windows

Comment: Have you added the lib also in the project settings, or in the code using pragma lib?

Comment: I have added the glog.lib found in the debug folder to the "Additional Dependencies" under the Linker tab in Visual studio.

Comment: Added #pragma comment(lib, <path>Debug\\glog.lib") and still the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. When you build the project in visual studio, there is also an "Installation" folder inside the MS project. I forgot to build that as well!